# sweet-modal-vue gives "Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined"

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I'm trying to build a *very* simple vue app that displays a modal. I'm using [sweet-modal-vue](http://sweet-modal-vue.adepto.as/). I am using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to bundle my app, primarily so that I can easily import sweet-modal-view into my app.

Something is breaking somewhere in the process and whenever I open my index.html file I get this error:

> Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
> Found in `<SweetModal>`

After looking for a solution I found almost everyone who had this problem solved it by aliasing vue to the full compiler build, as described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only). This did not work for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been banging my head against this for hours.

Versions:

```
Vue: 2.8.2
sweet-modal-vue: 5.3.0
Webpack: 3.4.1
```

Here are the relevant files, let me know if you'd like to see more:

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './app.vue';
import { SweetModal, SweetModalTab } from 'sweet-modal-vue';

new Vue({
  el: '#myapp',
  components: {
    SweetModal,
    SweetModalTab,
    App
  },
  data: {
    message: "Hello Vue"
  },
  methods: {
    openModal: function() {
        console.log(SweetModal);
        this.$refs.modal.open();
    }
  }
})
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vue Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myapp">
        <app></app>
        <h3>{{ message }}</h3>
        <sweet-modal ref="modal" icon="success">
            This is a success!!
        </sweet-modal>
        Accurate
        <button v-on:click="openModal()">Modal</button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="dist/build.js"></script>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  // This is the "main" file which should include all other modules
  context: __dirname,
  entry: __dirname + '/src/main.js',
  // Where should the compiled file go?
  output: {
    // To the `dist` folder
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: 'dist/',
    // With the filename `build.js` so it's dist/build.js
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    // Special compilation rules
    rules: [
      {
        // I tried this option as well, it didn't help
        // test: /\.vue$/,
        // loader: 'vue-loader',
        // options: {
        //   loaders: {
        //     // {{#sass}}
        //     // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
        //     // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
        //     // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
        //     'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
        //     'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        //     // {{/sass}}
        //   }
        //   // other vue-loader options go here
        // }
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
            loaders: {
                // Customize to your liking
                js: 'babel-loader',
                scss: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'}
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you define your vue template in a .vue file?

Comment: If I understand your question, I do not have a vue template, but sweet-modal-vue, the plugin I am using does have a .vue file in its internals.

Comment: In your `index.html` try removing the `<sweet-modal>` html tag, do you get any errors?

Comment: @bntz if I remove the `<sweet-modal>` tag I do not get any errors.

Comment: but you still see everything else working?

Comment: Yes, everything but the modal and the modal button works just fine. The 'Hello Vue' message text is properly displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150885/discussion-between-bntz-and-lnhubbell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by using a different modal package, there was something wrong with the sweet-modal-vue package itself.

If you're interested in following the problem, [here is the github issue](https://github.com/adeptoas/sweet-modal-vue/issues/30).